# Pandas drop duplicates does not behave as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series whose index contains several repeated items and I use `drop_duplicates` to have its index available for further slicing on other series/dataframes:

```
In[1]: test
Out[1]: 
5575    21010210
5575    21010210
5577    21010210
5577    21010210
5577    21010210
5583    21010210
5583    21010210
5583    21010210
5586    21010210
5586    21010210
5586    21010210
8545    21010210
8545    21010210
8718    21000102
8718    21000102
8721    21000102
8721    21000102
Name: CC, dtype: object
```

When I apply `test.drop_duplicates()`, I would expect all existing indices to remain, albeit without repetition. For some reason, pandas is not recognising some of those indices as duplicates and simply purges them from the dataframe:

```
In[2]: test.drop_duplicates()
Out[2]: 
5575    21010210
8718    21000102
Name: CC, dtype: object
```

Curiously, if I reset the index before, the `drop_duplicates` method will work correctly:

```
In[3]: test.reset_index().drop_duplicates()
Out[3]: 
    index        CC
0    5575  21010210
2    5577  21010210
5    5583  21010210
8    5586  21010210
11   8545  21010210
13   8718  21000102
15   8721  21000102
```

Any reasons why pandas will simply remove some of the indices from the operation? How do I effectively drop those duplicates without reseting the index?

Comment: Do you want to drop duplicates in the index or in the values? That's two different operations. `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` gets rid of duplicates in the values (optionally in specific columns only), the method for clearing the index of duplicates is `pd.Index.drop_duplicates`

Comment: You want `test.index.drop_duplicates`. In your first scenario you are dropping duplicates in your column values, notice index `5575 - 5545` all have the same value.

Comment: when you reset_index, the you passed two column as condition to drop_duplicates , before you set the index , you only pass the single value

Comment: @Erfan nailed it. My only question though is: using `test.index.drop_duplicates()` will return an Index object, is there a way to have that behaviour on the series? Two possible ways are `test.reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index()` and the other is `test.index.drop_duplicates().join()`, any others?

Comment: how about ``test.reset_index().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True).set_index('index')``?

Comment: You want: `test[~test.index.duplicated()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's your pandas `Series` object:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 
    21010210, 21010210,  21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 21010210, 
    21010210, 21000102, 21000102, 21000102, 21000102
]

idx = [
    5575, 5575, 5577, 5577, 5577, 5583, 5583, 5583, 
    5586, 5586, 5586, 8545, 8545, 8718, 8718, 8721, 8721
]

series = pd.Series(data, index=idx).rename("CC")

print(series)

>>>
5575    21010210
5575    21010210
5577    21010210
5577    21010210
5577    21010210
5583    21010210
5583    21010210
5583    21010210
5586    21010210
5586    21010210
5586    21010210
8545    21010210
8545    21010210
8718    21000102
8718    21000102
8721    21000102
8721    21000102
Name: CC, dtype: int64
```

Now, if you run [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), this will ignore your index:

> Return `DataFrame` with duplicate rows removed, optionally only
>   considering certain columns. **Indexes, including time indexes are
>   ignored**

```
print(series.drop_duplicates())

5575    21010210
8718    21000102
Name: CC, dtype: int64
```

Finally,  [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) will return a `dataframe` where the previous index is inserted into dataframe columns and the index will reset:

```
print(series.reset_index())
    index        CC
0    5575  21010210
1    5575  21010210
2    5577  21010210
3    5577  21010210
4    5577  21010210
5    5583  21010210
6    5583  21010210
7    5583  21010210
8    5586  21010210
9    5586  21010210
10   5586  21010210
11   8545  21010210
12   8545  21010210
13   8718  21000102
14   8718  21000102
15   8721  21000102
16   8721  21000102
```

> Reset the index of the DataFrame, and **use the default one instead**.

This means that `drop_duplicates()` will now consider both columns.

```
print(series.reset_index().drop_duplicates())
    index        CC
0    5575  21010210
2    5577  21010210
5    5583  21010210
8    5586  21010210
11   8545  21010210
13   8718  21000102
15   8721  21000102
```

The most effective way to do it is

```
print(series.loc[~series.index.duplicated()])
5575    21010210
5577    21010210
5583    21010210
5586    21010210
8545    21010210
8718    21000102
8721    21000102
Name: CC, dtype: int64
```